# Microsoft Graph API - List all Users who have access to a mail item?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I want to be able to have a list of all users who can view a certain mail item. As an admin on the frontend on exchange online, I can view all my users mail, but when i call to the API I only return my mail. I want to be able to make calls to see exactly who has permission to view each mail item, and cannot find a way through the api.

I can get a list of all users, and a list of all mail for each user, a list of all mailboxes, a list of all groups, but not permissions on each mail item

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages
```

returns all the mail, but mail items come with the following structure:

```
{
  "bccRecipients": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recipient"}],
  "body": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.itemBody"},
  "bodyPreview": "string",
  "categories": ["string"],
  "ccRecipients": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recipient"}],
  "changeKey": "string",
  "conversationId": "string",
  "createdDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "flag": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.followupFlag"},
  "from": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recipient"},
  "hasAttachments": true,
  "id": "string (identifier)",
  "importance": "String",
  "inferenceClassification": "String",
  "internetMessageHeaders": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.internetMessageHeader"}],
  "internetMessageId": "String",
  "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": true,
  "isDraft": true,
  "isRead": true,
  "isReadReceiptRequested": true,
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "parentFolderId": "string",
  "receivedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "replyTo": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recipient"}],
  "sender": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recipient"},
  "sentDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "subject": "string",
  "toRecipients": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recipient"}],
  "uniqueBody": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.itemBody"},
  "webLink": "string",

  "attachments": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.attachment"}],
  "extensions": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.extension"}],
  "multiValueExtendedProperties": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.multiValueLegacyExtendedProperty"}],
  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty"}]
}
```

this doesnt contain anything about the full permissions on the item. Does anyone know of a way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get item level permission as item doesn't store ACL associated with it. You can, however, get Folder level permission by querying PR_NT_SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR (0x0E270102) on the folder.

I actually wrote script for this based on my old REST API client engine: [Start-MailboxFolderPermissionReport](https://github.com/ivfranji/PowershellScripts/blob/master/EXO/Start-MailFolderPermissionReport.ps1)

I can, if script isn't enough, write C# way of doing it through [Graph Managed API](https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi)

Comment: was hoping for a multi platform way of doing it, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to expose mailbox or folder permissions through the Graph API.  These are available through the Exchange Online PowerShell module e.g. `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`.